# ticks under tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

There is my minimal code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{float,caption}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
x         y    error
-4.0  0.0296647842303  0.0291503887869
-3.0  0.0293603640735  0.0141878426016
-2.0  0.0286685720323  0.00649661240084
-1.0  0.0275361528438  0.00210364869319
2.0  0.0266314574388  0.00148277554508
3.0  0.0277962098809  0.00421008334229
4.0  0.0291488821404  0.00849079074145
}{\exp}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-4.5,
    xmax=4.5,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=0.06,
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    ylabel=$\delta(q)$,
    xlabel=moment $q$,
    legend columns=3,
    yticklabels={,,}
 ]
 \addplot[color=green,thin,error bars/.cd,y dir=both, y explicit] table[x=x,y=y,y error=error]  {\exp};     
 \end{axis} 
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

and there is my figure

[image]

I want to modify two things in this figure:
(1)first (and the most important) I do not want this pseudo tick "10^-2" at the top of the figure, I would like to have decimal numbers (0.002, 0.004, 0.006) as ylabel.
(2)secondly (this is less important) I would like to have an error bar only for x=-4 and x=4 (for example).

Comment: Use `scaled ticks=false` in the options for the `axis` environment.

Comment: You can use \pgfplotstablegettelem to pull specific numbers from the table to create a limited subset of error bars.

Answer (score 1):

Notice from the comments that if you had asked either of the single questions (or both in separate posts) you would have most likely gotten answer(s) to your question(s) the day you asked.

For the first problem, use `scaled y ticks=false`. This is needed because you zero out the tick *labels* with `yticklabels={,,}` (I'd prefer `yticklabels=\empty` by the way: it will work regardless of how many ticks are in the plot), but the ticks themselves are still placed, which means that the scaling may be in effect.

If you want the tick marks themselves gone, just use `ytick=empty` in place of `scaled y ticks=false,yticklabels={,,}`.

For the error bars, the quick and dirty solution is to remove the unwanted entries from the table. But I'm assuming your real use case has many more entries. We can create a new column (called `error-proc`) in the table `\exp` with

```
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
  <assignments>
]
{error-proc}{\exp}
```

The `<assignments>` part here is focused on grabbing only the first and last rows of `error` and copying only these elements into our new column `error-proc`:

```
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
  create col/assign first/.code={%
    \getthisrow{error}\entry
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
  },
  create col/assign last/.code={%
    \getthisrow{error}\entry
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
  },
]
{error-proc}{\exp}
```

Then just change `y error=error` to `y error=error-proc` in your `\addplot` command:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\pgfplotstableread{
x     y                error
-4.0  0.0296647842303  0.0291503887869
-3.0  0.0293603640735  0.0141878426016
-2.0  0.0286685720323  0.00649661240084
-1.0  0.0275361528438  0.00210364869319
 2.0  0.0266314574388  0.00148277554508
 3.0  0.0277962098809  0.00421008334229
 4.0  0.0291488821404  0.00849079074145
}{\exp}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
  create col/assign first/.code={%
    \getthisrow{error}\entry
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
  },
  create col/assign last/.code={%
    \getthisrow{error}\entry
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
  },
]
{error-proc}{\exp}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=-4.5,
  xmax=4.5,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=0.06,
  axis background/.style={fill=white},
  ylabel=$\delta(q)$,
  xlabel=moment $q$,
  yticklabels=\empty,
  scaled y ticks=false,
]
\addplot[error bars/.cd,y dir=both, y explicit] table[x=x,y=y,y error=error-proc]  {\exp};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]